# Add post meta programmatically to attachment

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, attachments

I have a function to create a meta key for my custom post types. It works pretty well for them but now I want to use the same function for the `attachment` post type.

- Normally it should work with the hook: `add_action('add attachment',
  'bZive_generate_AlphanumericID', 10, 3);`
- Because it's pretty much the same as (which works!):
  `add_action('wp_insert_post', 'bZive_generate_AlphanumericID', 10, 3);`

But for some reason no keys are getting generated (I checked my db in the postmeta table - also in the right blog...)

**Here the full code**

```
function bZive_generate_AlphanumericID( $post_id ) {

    $postTypes = array('profile', 'article', 'attachment');
    $postType = get_post_type( $post_id );

    if (in_array( $postType, $postTypes ) and empty( get_post_meta( $post_id, 'alphanumeric_id', true ) ) ) {


        $characters = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ'$§%&!";

        $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
        $randomString = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < 13; $i++) {
            $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
        }


         /**
         * Now check here if the string is in the database
         */
        $args = array(
        'post_type'     =>  array(
                $postTypes 
            ),
        'meta_query'    =>  array(
            array(
                'meta_key'  =>  'alphanumeric_id'
            )
        )
        );
        $posts = new WP_Query( $args );


        $meta_values = '';
        if( $posts->have_posts() ) {
          while( $posts->have_posts() ) {
            $posts->the_post();

            $meta_values[] = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'alphanumeric_id', true );
          }
        } 
        wp_reset_postdata();


        if (in_array( $randomString, $meta_values )) {
            // "Match found"
            return generate_AlphanumericID;

        }  else {
            // "Match not found"
            add_post_meta($post_id, 'alphanumeric_id', $randomString);
            return $randomString;

        }

    }

}
add_action('wp_insert_post', 'bZive_generate_AlphanumericID', 10, 3);
add_action('add attachment', 'bZive_generate_AlphanumericID', 10, 3);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing an underscore:

`add_action('add attachment', 'bZive_generate_AlphanumericID', 10, 3);`

Needs to be:

`add_action('add_attachment', 'bZive_generate_AlphanumericID', 10, 1);`

I also changed the number of accepted arguments to `1`, because `add_attachment` only has 1 and your callback function is only using 1 anyway.

Comment: Yea ok, thanks but after I posted this I saw it by my self - you were quicker :)